# SQL based Excel add-in fails to connect to Database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, excel-addins

I have coded an Excel Add-in using C# in Visual Studio 2010  where some data from Excel sheets are saved to an SQL database. I have used Entity Framework Code  First to create the connection to my SQL database (in .Net environment).
When i debug the code it works absolutely fine and the database connection is OK. But when i install the deployed file, the database connection fails somehow,  and I get the error "No connection string named 'ConString' could be found in the application config file".
I have the the app.config file in the main project and not in the Setup file, do i need a config file for that as well? is such a thing possible?

this is app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<configSections><section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" /></configSections>

<connectionStrings> <add name="ConString" connectionString="Data Source=***;Initial Catalog***;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=***;Password=***" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /></connectionStrings>

<entityFramework><defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
 <providers><provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"      type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" /></providers> </entityFramework>
 </configuration>
```

and .cs

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
namespace SourceManager
{
    public partial class SourceDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public SourceDBContext() : base("name=ConString"){}
        public virtual DbSet<Source> Sources { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you confirm that when deploying that your config settings are correct..? that the machine that you are deploying it on you have the dependencies set to copylocal = true for things such as SqlDataClient.dll, this sounds like a reference issue can you also tell us what any of the errors are..if no errors..then I would suggest adding some logging to the code so that you can determine what the actual error(s) are ... also make sure that the target machine has .net framework installed on it as well

Comment: Sounds like you need to add some error-handling and reporting/logging.

Comment: The error is No connection string Name 'ConString' could be foud in the application config file. But the connection is fine during debug. @MethodMan can you please tell me how i can set those configurations?

Comment: @srinced are you using an app.config file..? also in order for us to help you you need to show the config file as well as the code you are using.. the error is telling you exactly what the problem is.. is there a typo in the way that you are trying to assign the value. for example do you have something like this in your code
`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConString"];` can't tell unless you show the connectionstring portion of the config file.. also when you deploy the app the app.config does not get deployed..it's the `applicationname.exe.config` that gets deployed meaning your app name

Comment: @MethodMan yes I use app.config file

Comment: where in the .cs file are you assigning this `ConString` please edit your question and post all relevant code...